# html email mouse over text

Tags: python, html, email, outlook

Using python to send hourly reports in HTML. Need to enable mouse over text, in other words, when a user hovers his mouse over the report title certain text is displayed.

Tried the below, but it does work when the reading the email in outlook:

```
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText

def send_html_email(msg_to_list, msg_from, msg_subject, msg_body, smtp_server):
    ''' set the subject, To, From and body of the email and send it '''
    # Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
    msg = MIMEMultipart('multipart')
    msg['Subject'] = msg_subject
    msg['From'] = msg_from
    msg['To'] = ', '.join(msg_to_list)
    # Record the MIME type of the HTML body - text/html.
    part = MIMEText(msg_body, 'html')
    # Attach parts into message container.
    msg.attach(part)
    # Send the message via local SMTP server.
    s = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server)
    # sendmail function takes 3 arguments: sender's address, recipient's address
    # and message to send - here it is sent as one string.
    s.sendmail(msg['From'], msg_to_list, msg.as_string())
    s.quit()


title = 'display this when user moves mouse over this header'
html_msg_body = '''<html><body><div align = "center">'''
html_msg_body += '''<br><br><h3 bgcolor="#00BFFF" title=%s>Stats</h3>'''%(title)
html_msg_body += '<br></body>'
html_msg_body += '<br></html>'


msg_body = html_msg_body
msg_to_list = ['me@test.com']
msg_from = 'me@test.com'
msg_subject = "Stats"
smtp_server = 'localhost'
send_html_email(msg_to_list, msg_from, msg_subject, msg_body, smtp_server)
```

Any help on what needs to be done so outlook displays mouse over text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Unfortunately, Hover effects are not supported in Outlook 2007/2010, Gmail, iOS or Android. The supporting clients are: Outlook 2000/2003, Hotmail, Apple Mail, and Yahoo! mail.](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/design-perfect-newsletter/)

Comment: thanks, any suggestions for best alternatives to do the task I am aiming for?

Comment: You can't do it, plain and simple. Sorry about that. The best you can do is make it work in Outlook 2000 / 2003, Hotmail, Apple Mail, and Yahoo! mail (your code will already work on those clients). Sorry about that, but most email clients block it for security reasons.